# ceres-solver, simple program, c++

Tags: c++, ceres-solver

I am getting used to using Google's Ceres-Solver,
but I can't understand this C++ syntax (even with the description).

What exactly is going on here? :

```
 template <typename T>
 bool operator()(const T* const x, T* residual) const {
```

[image]

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: Extending on @NathanOliver 's comments, here's a piece on templated functions that happily uses a functor as an example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template